# Can we generate cucumber html report while running in multiple browsers

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor-cucumber frame work(cucumber 3.2). I have specified

```
multiCapabilities: [
  { 'browserName': 'chrome' }, 
  { 'browserName': 'firefox' },
  { 'browserName': 'internet explorer' }
]
```

in the config file.And when i am running, i got an error

```
 "Unable to parse cucumberjs output into json.
```

But when I am running with single browser,report is generating perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this package: [protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin)